# Bone is lost in pose mode

Tags: rigging

In Object mode, all of finger rigs are visible, but in pose mode, 
I can not see a single finger rig. 
Even if I press ALT + H, I can not see bone. 
If you do not have an easy solution, 
is there a way to create a temporary skeleton?

Here is a .blender file(98mb, download it from Chrome): https://drive.google.com/open?id=12gr2WdT6wYQw2TzCG8IAh1M1zN6jndMp

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select your bone in *Edit* mode, then switch to *Pose* mode and reactivate the *Wireframe* option in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Display*

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Where can i find Finger2.R ? I can not find it.

Comment: select it in Edit mode then switch to Pose mode